# Angular 2+: Error: Unexpected closing tag "div" - Uncaught Error: Template parse errors

Tags: html, angular

I've been staring and toying with this html code block for a simple Angular 4 page, and no matter what I do, looking for typos and searches on the errors it keeps giving me a hard time with my  closing tags.

**Error Message:

Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "div". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag.   /div>  /div> [ERROR ->]/div>**

```
  <form [formGroup]="form">

    <!-- OLD PASSWORD -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Old Password</label>
      <input formControlName="oldPassword" type="password" class="form-control">
         <div 
           *ngIf="oldPassword.touched && oldPassword.invalid" 
           class="alert alert-danger">
              <div *ngIf="oldPassword.errors.required">
                  Old password is required.
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>


    <!-- NEW PASSWORD -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">New Password</label>
        <input formControlName="newPassword" type="password" class="form-control">
        <div 
          *ngIf="newPassword.touched && newPassword.invalid" 
           class="alert alert-danger">
             <div *ngIf="newPassword.errors.required">New password is required.</div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- CONFIRM PASSWORD -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Confirm Password</label>
        <input formControlName="confirmPassword" type="password" class="form-control">
        <div 
          *ngIf="confirmPassword.touched && confirmPassword.invalid" 
           class="alert alert-danger">
             <div *ngIf="confirmPassword.errors.required">Confirm password is required.</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary">Change Password</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: You get this error in the editor, or when doing a production build, or...?
For what it's worth, I copied your code into an Angular project file and didn't see the error. Sometimes VS Code shows false errors. I'd recommend restarting it.

Comment: When I open this project in Chrome, nothing loads and this error is shown in the Chrome console. I have tried going back to a previous iteration of this project to see if I messed up some other file further up the chain but they seem to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

**[SOLVED]  after pretty much turning this project upside-down and inside-out it seems my problem was that I had two components that were very similarly named:**

"change-password"

and then

"change-password-reactive"

**I had to removed the instance of "change-password" from my app.module.ts to get the page to load and this error to go away.**

Comment: The error indicate you that your html has a "div" and it must not have it. Perhaps an unclosed quote can be the cause